# JQGrid custom_element function firing only for the first time

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using a custom edit type for radio buttons in jqgrid. After selecting the row and clicked on edit everything is working fine for the first time. But from second time it is not even calling the function mentioned in custom_element.

My jqgrid column specification is below.

```
{name: "StatusName", editable: true, edittype: "custom", editoptions: {custom_element: radioelement, custom_value: radiovalue}}
```

The custom_element function is:

```
function radioelement(value, options) {
        var receivedradio = '<input type="radio" name="status" value="Active"',
                breakline = '/>Active<br>',
                naradio = '<input type="radio" name="status" value="InActive"',
                endnaradio = '/>Inactive<br>';

        if (value === 'Active') {
            return "<span>" + receivedradio + ' checked="checked"' + breakline + naradio + endnaradio + "</span>";
        }
        if (value === 'InActive') {
            return "<span>" + receivedradio + breakline + naradio + ' checked="checked"' + endnaradio + "</span>";
        }
        return "<span>" + receivedradio + breakline + naradio + endnaradio + "</span>";
    };
```

The custom_value function is:

```
function radiovalue(elem, operation, value) {
        if (operation === 'get') {
            return $(elem).val();
        } else if (operation === 'set') {
            if ($(elem).is(':checked') === false) {
                $(elem).filter('[value=' + value + ']').attr('checked', true);
            }
        }
    };
```

Please help me out of this

Comment: I have the same problem, how did you solve it?